# Last Opened not clickable in Applications folder View Options

Tags: snow-leopard, finder, folders, sort

I’m trying to sort my applications by *Last Opened* column, but the option is not clickable (is grayed out) in the view options (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) panel (see image below).

Why and how can I fix this?

(I’m on Snow Leopard 10.6.8)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date last opened was only available in Spotlight windows in 10.6 and earlier. It became available in normal Finder windows in 10.7.

http://www.mac-help.com/t205135-does-snow-leopard-have-last-opened.html

> > One thing that's always annoyed me about Leopard is that the search
> >     results window has a Last Opened column, but an ordinary Finder window
> >     doesn't have that option.
> >
> > Of course, it also annoys me that the search results window is not an
> >     ordinary Finder window like it used to be, with Size, Created and all
> >     the other column options.
> >
> > Has Snow Leopard fixed this inconsistency?
>
> In list view 'Last Opened' is one of the options in Show View Options,
>   but it's rather annoyingly greyed out.
>
> So: Yes, but no.

Answer (score -1):

Requires a little bit of fiddling about but pretty simple to fix, check out:
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2009083113534843

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.